# Error: Dry mode when moving Z-Axis

Tags: heated-bed

My printer just stopped working. It seems like it's working perfectly, but it gives me an error whenever I move the Z-Axis (Error: Printer set into dry run mode until restart) then, the bed temperature appears to be at 293ºC when it's actually at 95ºC.

I suspect that the bed wires short-circuited since they got stuck behind the bed when the printer was moving Y-Axis to home (the wires blocked the movement). Since then, the error appeared.

I suspect that the controller board could have been harmed by the supposed short-circuit, but despite the error, I can move perfectly any axis; I can heat the bed and the extruder; I can extrude filament; it is just the error which doesn't let me print.

**Printer:**
Anet A8 Desktop 3D Printer Prusa i3

**Software:**
MatterHackers: MatterControl 1.7

**Update:** The bed temperature is stuck at ~95ºC, sometimes ~250ºC, even if I disconnect the sensor wires and restart the printer, so apparently, it's failing to read the bed temperature.

Comment: is at least anybody having the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a new board controller and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the wiring on your motherboard and all of the connections to your steppers. When I first had my printer, the z-axis didn't work because a wire was loose. I took apart the control box on my Di3 and made sure everything was firmly connected, and after that everything worked fine.

Comment: The wiring is ok and firmly connected, actually everything works fine but bed's temp, however, I'm not able to print anything since it enables dry mode cooling the extruder, aI'm pretty sure that the controller board has been harmed, I'm waiting for a replacement which should arrive this week, I also will try burning a custom firmware to the harmed controller board. I'll update soon

Comment: Are you saying everything except for the bed heating up works? If yes, most likely the connector on the mainboard burned. This happened to me for the wanhao i3 and I am getting a replacement. The connectors are not rated for high voltages, so they burn/melt.

Comment: I think I shortcircuited GND and Data+ from heating bed and that harmed the mainboard, even if I desconnect the heating bed, printer still showing always 95ºC, it may be a random value, or maybe it's the last value that printer read from the bed and got stuck in ROM or something, I have no idea